# How to output Pandas object from sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have constructed a pipeline that takes a pandas dataframe that has been split into categorical and numerical columns. I am trying to run GridSearchCV on my results and ultimately look at the ranked features of importance for the best performing model that GridSearchCV selects. The problem I am encountering is that sklearn pipelines output numpy array objects and lose any column information along the way. Thus when I go to examine the most important coefficients of the model I am left with an unlabeled numpy array.

I have read that building a custom transformer might be a possible solution to this, but I do not have any experience doing so myself. I have also looked into leveraging the sklearn-pandas package, but I am hesitant to try and implement something that might not be updated in parallel with sklearn. Can anyone suggest what they believe is the best path to go about getting around this issue? I am also open to any literature that has hands on application of pandas and sklearn pipelines.

My Pipeline:

```
# impute and standardize numeric data 
numeric_transformer = Pipeline([
    ('impute', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy="mean")),
    ('scale', StandardScaler())
])

# impute and encode dummy variables for categorical data
categorical_transformer = Pipeline([
    ('impute', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy="most_frequent")),
    ('one_hot', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown='ignore'))
])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
    ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)
])

clf = Pipeline([
    ('transform', preprocessor),
    ('ridge', Ridge())
])
```

Cross Validation:

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=44)

cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=kf).mean()
```

Grid Search:

```
param_grid = {
    'ridge__alpha': [.001, .1, 1.0, 5, 10, 100]
}

gs = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid, cv = kf)
gs.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Examining Coefficients:

```
model = gs.best_estimator_
predictions = model.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
model.named_steps['ridge'].coef_
```

Here is the output of the model coefficients as it currently stands when performed on the seaborn "mpg" dataset:

```
array([-4.64782052e-01,  1.47805207e+00, -3.28948689e-01, -5.37033173e+00,
        2.80000700e-01,  2.71523808e+00,  6.29170887e-01,  9.51627968e-01,
       ...
       -1.50574860e+00,  1.88477450e+00,  4.57285471e+00, -6.90459868e-01,
        5.49416409e+00])
```

Ideally I would like to preserve the pandas dataframe information and retrieve the derived column names after OneHotEncoder and the other methods are called.

Comment: [this](https://ramhiser.com/post/2018-04-16-building-scikit-learn-pipeline-with-pandas-dataframe/)  might help

Comment: Can't you just pass the input to the 'transform' layer of the pipeline and get the column names corresponding to the input (X_train_transf) of the 'ridge' layer from there?When using the `Ridge` class in sklearn, the `.coef` array stores the coefficients of your fitted model and the order is preserved so if you know the columns names you can just map them to your 'unlabeled' array: `param_coef_df = pd.DataFrame({'feature':X_train_transf.columns, 'coefficient': model.named_steps['ridge'].coef_})` ,

`param_coef_df = param_coef_df.sort_values(by='coefficient')`

Comment: @JacoSolari do you mind turning that comment into an answer showing a working example?

Comment: @JacoSolari It has been some time since I have revisited this question, but yes in my own work I have implemented that same logic in my code to combine the transformed coefficient names into a pandas dataframe. I believe there is still the limitation of having to call each individual transformation as a named step when dealing with pipelines. It would be great if the ColumnTransformer.get_feature_names method supported pipelines, but as of right now it does not.

Comment: @lurscher I added an answer, let me know if it suites your need.

Answer (score 4):

I would actually go for creating column names from the input. If your input is already divided into numerical an categorical you can use `pd.get_dummies` to get the number of different category for each categorical feature.

Then you can just create proper names for the columns as shown in the last part of this working example based on the question with some artificial data.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score, GridSearchCV

# create aritificial data
numeric_features_vals = pd.DataFrame({'x1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'x2': [0.15, 0.25, 0.5, 0.45]})
numeric_features = ['x1', 'x2']
categorical_features_vals = pd.DataFrame({'cat1': [0, 1, 1, 2], 'cat2': [2, 1, 5, 0] })
categorical_features = ['cat1', 'cat2']

X_train = pd.concat([numeric_features_vals, categorical_features_vals], axis=1)
X_test = pd.DataFrame({'x1':[2,3], 'x2':[0.2, 0.3], 'cat1':[0, 1], 'cat2':[2, 1]})
y_train = pd.DataFrame({'labels': [10, 20, 30, 40]})

# impute and standardize numeric data 
numeric_transformer = Pipeline([
    ('impute', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy="mean")),
    ('scale', StandardScaler())
])

# impute and encode dummy variables for categorical data
categorical_transformer = Pipeline([
    ('impute', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy="most_frequent")),
    ('one_hot', OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown='ignore'))
])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
    ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)
])

clf = Pipeline([
    ('transform', preprocessor),
    ('ridge', Ridge())
])


kf = KFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True, random_state=44)
cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=kf).mean()

param_grid = {
    'ridge__alpha': [.001, .1, 1.0, 5, 10, 100]
}

gs = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid, cv = kf)
gs.fit(X_train, y_train)

model = gs.best_estimator_
predictions = model.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
print('coefficients : ',  model.named_steps['ridge'].coef_, '\n')

# create column names for categorical hot encoded data
columns_names_to_map = list(np.copy(numeric_features))
columns_names_to_map.extend('cat1_' + str(col) for col in pd.get_dummies(X_train['cat1']).columns)
columns_names_to_map.extend('cat2_' + str(col) for col in pd.get_dummies(X_train['cat2']).columns)

print('columns after preprocessing :', columns_names_to_map,  '\n')
print('#'*80)
print( '\n', 'dataframe of rescaled features with custom colum names: \n\n', pd.DataFrame({col:vals for vals, col in zip (preprocessor.fit_transform(X_train).T, columns_names_to_map)}))
print('#'*80)
print( '\n', 'dataframe of ridge coefficients with custom colum names: \n\n', pd.DataFrame({col:vals for vals, col in zip (model.named_steps['ridge'].coef_.T, columns_names_to_map)}))
```

the code above (in the end) prints out the following dataframe which is a map from parameter name to parameter value:

[image]

Comment: but how do you retrieve any columns that `SimpleImputer.fit_transform` might have dropped? or columns that `SimpleImputer.fit` will drop

Comment: As far as I know `SimpleImputer` only drops columns that contain **only** missing values (at least when `strategy='constant'`).  Anyways, if for any reason a column is dropped before the Ridge block, my code will throw an error as the length of the Ridge model coefficient and the column names in `columns_names_to_map` will be different.

Comment: Alternatively, you could bypass the `Imputer` and just go for `df.fillna(a_value_you_compute)` to replace missing values (which in Pandas DataFrames are most of the times `np.nan`).

Answer (score 0):

I would use `model.named_steps['transform'].get_feature_names_out()`.

It will return the feature names like this:

```
array(['num__cylinders', 'num__displacement', 'num__horsepower',
       'num__weight', 'num__acceleration', 'num__model_year',
       'cat__origin_europe', 'cat__origin_japan', 'cat__origin_usa',...])
```

Then you can use the feature names to transform the output to a dataframe:

```
weights_df = pd.DataFrame(model.named_steps['ridge'].coef_,index=model.named_steps['transform'].get_feature_names_out()).T
```

Answer (score 0):

In sklearn 1.2 and higher, you can use the following to get pandas dataframes as output of sklearn transformers:

```
from sklearn import set_config
set_config(transform_output = "pandas")
```